# get current user screen to display or not remote notification alert

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am implementing remote notifications in my app:

I am controlling the behavior of the remote notification when the app is in foreground with

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler
completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) ->
Void)
```

I am using those 3 different options for the completion handler :

```
completionHandler([.alert, .sound])
completionHandler([.sound])
```

I have for instance 2 screens in my app:

- Home
- List of conversation

When the user is using my app and receive a remote notification for a conversation update, I want:

- If he is on the home screen -> completionHandler([.alert, .sound])
- If he is on the list of conversation screen -> completionHandler([.sound])

My app has many different screens which can trigger different types of remote notification. 
What is the best way to get the current viewed screen and choose the completion handler needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way would be to check the current visible controller (the top view controller). The code looking for the top most one is:

```
extension UIApplication {
    static func topViewController(controller: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let navigationController = controller as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(controller: navigationController.visibleViewController)
        }
        if let tabController = controller as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tabController.selectedViewController {
                return topViewController(controller: selected)
            }
        }
        if let presented = controller?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(controller: presented)
        }
        return controller
    }
}
```

Then, when choosing whenever to present the notification or not, you could just do something like:

```
if UIApplication.topViewController() is HomeViewController {
    // Top controller is Home
}
```

This can be called from any point in the app.

Comment: That is definitely what I need. 
Is It not if UIApplication.topViewController() is HomeViewController instead of if UIApplication.topViewController is HomeViewController ?